# Blind Sql injection in application developed using spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC for developing my web application.My problem is ,when I have done APPSCAN of my web application,it report BLIND SQL INJECTION in many of parameters in my SPRING MVC form.I am using bean for fetching data from SPRING MVC form and save() function in Spring framework for saving data to database.How I can resolve my ploblem?

My sample code is below..

Login.jsp contains link

```
<script>
function openUserReg(){
 window.open("/ma/UserReg.nic");
}
</script>
<body>
<form:form>
<a href="#" onclick="openUserReg();">Producer/ Dealer Registration(Public)</a>
</form>
</body>
```

configuration of `UserReg.nic` is

```
<beans>
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="mappings">
<props>
<prop key="UserReg.nic">UserRegController</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="UserRegController" class="nic.mams.web.UserRegController">
<property name="commandName"><value>userReg</value></property>
<property name="commandClass"><value>nic.mams.web.beans.UserRegBean</value></property>
<property name="validator" ref ="UserRegValidator"/>
<property name="userRegService" ref="UserRegService"/>
<property name="pages">
<list>
<value>userRegistration.jsp</value>
<value>successRegistration.jsp</value>
</list>
</property>
</bean>
```

**userRegistration.jsp** contains

```
<form:input path="name" id="name" cssClass="control" maxlength="25" onclick="hidErMsg('er01');hidErMsgInnerHtml('err1');" autocomplete="off"/>
```

And the controller class contains the code

```
    public class UserRegController extends AbstractWizardFormController{
    UserRegService userRegService;

    protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest req, Object obj, Errors er, int page) throws Exception {.....

   return map;
   }
protected ModelAndView processFinish(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res, Object obj, BindException be) throws Exception {

UserRegBean bean = (UserRegBean)obj;

Applicant app=new Applicant();

...
app.setName(bean.getName());

userRegService.saveApp(app);

}

}
```

saveApp(app) function in UserRegService contains the code

```
saveApp(app){

        String success = "No";
        Session session=getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            getHibernateTemplate().save(app);
            tx.commit();
            session.close();
            success = "Yes";
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
        }
        if (success.equals("Yes")){
            return getHibernateTemplate().find("SELECT DISTINCT l.applicantLoginId,l.username,a.appServiceId,a.name,a.panNo " +
                "FROM ApplicantLogin as l INNER JOIN l.applicants as a " +
                "WHERE l.applicantLoginId=? AND l.applicantLoginId=a.applicantLogin AND a.applicantStatus is null " +
                    "AND a.transferType is null AND a.registrationStatus is not null ",applntlg.getApplicantLoginId());
        }
        return null;


}
```

Appscan results this

```
 [17 of 26] Blind SQL Injection
    Severity: High
    Test Type: Application
    Vulnerable URL: UserReg.nic (Parameter: name)
    CVE ID(s): N/A
    CWE ID(s): 89    
Remediation Tasks: Review possible solutions for hazardous character injection
```

Any one any suggestion please provide me.

Comment: I really hope that this isn't production code?! You shouldn't be opening new hibernate sessions and start transactions yourself (currently you have 2 sessions and 2 transactions, 1 spring managed and one for yourself). You are basically copying everything straight from the input into your code. Now if some malicious user enters something like `javascript:alert('Hello');` on subsequent requests that might execute. (XSS attack), the SQL injection you can ignore (IMHO) as hibernate uses a `Statement` to add the parameters and not string concat.

Comment: can u demonstrate by example

Comment: How I can remove Blind Sql injection from my code,sir?

Comment: Is it a problem? It only does a static code check if everything is escaped before you copy the fields there is not a problem. So first make sure that it actually is a problem. And read the documentation of the tools you use they probably have some suggestions on what/how to improve.